# R | How to arrange in custom order character vectors of a df column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Fruit | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple, banana, orange, papaya | a | f | k |
| banana, orange, grape | b | g | l |
| orange, banana | c | h | m |
| grape | d | i | n |
| banana, grape, orange, apple, papaya | e | j | o |

And I want to set a custom order of appearance in each row. Like:

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Papaya
4. Banana
5. Grape

So the column would look like:

| Fruit | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple, orange, papaya, banana | a | f | k |
| orange, banana, grape | b | g | l |
| orange, banana | c | h | m |
| grape | d | i | n |
| apple, orange, papaya, banana, grape | e | j | o |

How can I do this??? I've tried suggestions from other posts, but they're all about arranging dataframe rows, which isn't what I need...

P.S.: is there any way to do this inside a pipe?

Comment: Is your `Fruit` column class `character` or class `list`? Could you please share your sample data with `dput()`, that is `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` to make it easy to import and to clear up any data structure confusion?

Comment: structure(character(Fruit = c("apple, banana, orange, papaya", "banana, orange, grape", 
"orange, banana", "grape", "banana, grape, orange, apple, papaya"
), X = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), Y = c("f", "g", "h", "i", 
"j"), Z = c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Comment: @not_ginn Do you have a `list` or `character` column

Comment: A character column!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one more (a tidyverse solution):

Main feature is to use `separate_rows` and then create `factor` class with the levels:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(Fruit) %>% 
  mutate(Fruit= factor(Fruit, levels = c("apple", "orange", "papaya", "banana", "grape"))) %>% 
  arrange(Fruit, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(Fruit = toString(Fruit)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df[2:4]) %>% 
  select(-group)
```

```
  Fruit                                X     Y     Z    
  <chr>                                <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 apple, orange, papaya, banana        a     f     k    
2 orange, banana, grape                b     g     l    
3 orange, banana                       c     h     m    
4 grape                                d     i     n    
5 apple, orange, papaya, banana, grape e     j     o
```

Comment: OMG!!! It almost worked!!!

Comment: The only problem though is that the actual values of this column are: "5'-UTR", "Intron", "Exon", "3'-UTR", and "RNAm"... So when I run this pipe, some values like 5'-UTR and 3'-UTR become NA

Comment: replace the second row with separate_rows... with `separate_rows(Fruit, sep=",") `

Comment: Just tried separate_rows (Fruit, sep = ",") and now only "orange" shows up, the rest's NA

Comment: could you provide the output of `dput(head(yourdataframename))`. Otherwise it is a guess all the time and not interesting.

Comment: you have to adapt the levels in fatctor(Fruit, levels = c("apple", .... with your corresponding names...

Comment: I posted another question trying to figure this one out, and, embarassingly, my problem was whitespace on both sides of the string. Now your suggestion works!!! Thank you so much!!!  Now I'm pretty happy with the final result :3

Answer (score 4):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(Fruit = map_chr(strsplit(Fruit, ",\\s*"), 
        ~ toString(.x[order(match(.x,
  c("apple", "orange", "papaya", "banana", "grape")))])))
```

-output

```
df1
                                  Fruit X Y Z
1        apple, orange, papaya, banana a f k
2                orange, banana, grape b g l
3                       orange, banana c h m
4                                grape d i n
5 apple, orange, papaya, banana, grape e j o
```

---

Or using `separate_longer_delim`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Fruit, delim = regex(",\\s*")) %>% 
  arrange(rn, factor(Fruit, 
   levels = c("apple", "orange", "papaya", "banana", "grape"))) %>% 
  reframe(Fruit = str_c(Fruit, collapse = ", "),
    .by = c("rn", "X", "Y", "Z")) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>%
  relocate(Fruit, .before = 1)
```

-output

```
df1
                                 Fruit X Y Z
1        apple, orange, papaya, banana a f k
2                orange, banana, grape b g l
3                       orange, banana c h m
4                                grape d i n
5 apple, orange, papaya, banana, grape e j o
```

---

If the column is `list`, we don't need the `strsplit`, instead

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(Fruit = map(Fruit, 
  ~ .x[order(match(.x, c("apple", "orange", "papaya", "banana", "grape")))]))
```

---

Or with `unnest`

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest(Fruit) %>% 
  arrange(rn, factor(Fruit, 
   levels = c("apple", "orange", "papaya", "banana", "grape"))) %>% 
  reframe(Fruit = list(Fruit),
    .by = c("rn", "X", "Y", "Z")) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>%
  relocate(Fruit, .before = 1)
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Fruit     X     Y     Z    
  <list>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 <chr [4]> a     f     k    
2 <chr [3]> b     g     l    
3 <chr [2]> c     h     m    
4 <chr [1]> d     i     n    
5 <chr [5]> e     j     o
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Fruit = c("apple, banana, orange, papaya", "banana, orange, grape", 
"orange, banana", "grape", "banana, grape, orange, apple, papaya"
), X = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), Y = c("f", "g", "h", "i", 
"j"), Z = c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: sadly, it didn't seem to work here 

Comment: @not_ginn your dput is not working correctly to test

Comment: yeah, I just saw it... in this example, it's a list column, but in my original df, it's a character column. If I convert it, will it work? Let me try it here

Comment: @not_ginn `structure(character(Fruit = c(` seems unusual,.  isn't it `structure(list(Fruit = c("apple,...`   Is the output from `dput` or your own manual insertion of `character(`

Comment: @not_ginn If you have both cases, either one of the solution (first one - for character and second - for list column should work)

Comment: My original dataframe column class is character... when I try @akrun's first solution, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @not_ginn thanks, can you give more info about doesn't work or is it confidential

Comment: I'm so sorry I can't show you the data, but... like, though it works, when I view the df, the column's exactly the same... nothing's changed.

Comment: @not_ginn you need to assign to modify the original object.  It doesn't do in place update of the original object. `df1 <- df1 %>% ...`  sorry, I must have mentioned it

Comment: But I am assigning... this should be the last chunk of a bigger pipe

Comment: @not_ginn Not clear.  If you have assigned to the orignal object, it should have changed.  Maybe try on a fresh R session

Comment: Just did, and still isn't working... =//

Comment: @not_ginn Not sure what is the issue in your console.  Is it on Rstudio

Comment: I'm using RStudio, yes... but thank you so much for your help  I'll see what I can do around here now!